# Регулярное выражение для проверки на валидность числа

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти в строке подстроку с валидным числом, то есть: "123.123" валидно, а ".123" или "123." не валидно

я пробую так:

```
Pattern.compile("[^0-9][\\.]{0,1}([0-9]){1,}")
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: странная регулярка. Кстати, она пропустит `.123` - первые квадратные скобки захватят точку.

А какой язык программирования, что приходиться так страшно писать регулярку (явно нет поддержки `+`, `?` и `*`)

Comment: java, получаю первый опыт с регулярками

Comment: Определите, пожалуйста, что такое "валидное число". Не примерами, а правилами: "валидное число - это такая последовательность символов, что в начале идут..."

Comment: у мне есть строка с выражением, я хочу проверить все ли числа соответсвуют моим ожиданием, а именно  ".123" или "123." я не ожидаю, так же я не ожидаю больше одного арифметического действия т.е. 123 + -123

Comment: Минимизируйте вопрос настолько, чтобы на него можно было дать конкретный ответ. В комментариях слишком много "шума" добавилось. Советую добавить в вопрос: 1) код, 2) примерный валидный текст, 3) пример невалидного текста, 4) конкретные требования.

Comment: Попробуйте [`s.matches("[-+]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*[-/*+]\\s*[-+]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?")`](https://regex101.com/r/6JBzR5/1)

Answer (score 2):

В регулярке много "странностей". Например, `{0,1}` - это просто `?`. `{1,}` - это просто `+`. Ну и так дальше. То есть, как минимум, вышеприведенную регулярку можно переписать так (я убираю экранирование, которое требуется java)

```
было  [^0-9][\.]{0,1}([0-9]){1,}
стало \D\.?(\d)+
```

Теперь видна ошибка - последние скобки не захватывают плюс. Поэтому, если там будет три цифры, то будет три группы.

Как переписать красиво? Что такое число - это одна и более цифр, после которой может быть точка и ещё цифры. Прямо так и запишем

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

и это все.

Если нужно учитывать и знак, тогда так

```
[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?
```

Найдите книгу "Регулярные выражения. Дж. Фридл." и прочитайте. Там есть и о java. и о подводных камнях. Сильно поможет.

Comment: вообще-то ваше регулярное выражение пропустит строку `12.`, т.к. найдет в ней совпадение в подстроке `12`

Comment: ничего не пропустит. Все отработает как нужно. Выражение не захватит точку. Но если у нас длинная строка и число в самом конце. В этом случае точка хоть и есть, но числу не пренадлежит. А это уже интереснее:) Другое дело, что регулярки в java могут неявно вставлять `^`/`$` с вытекающими последствиями.

Comment: Спасибо за то что уделили на меня свое время, книжку обязательно прочту!)

Comment: @KoVadim в вопросе написано, что строка ".123" - не валидна. а у вас будет валидна, потому что если подать на вход всю строку, оно даст совпадение.

Comment: Мой комментарий выше все равно подходит:)

Comment: Не могли бы помочь переписать регулярки на новый лад:

Comment: if (expression.matches(".*[^0-9]([\\.]){1}[0-9].*") || expression.matches(".*[0-9]([\\.]){1}[^0-9].*") ||
    expression.matches("^[\\.].*") || expression.matches(".*[\\.$]"))
   throw new IllegalStateException("Expression invalid character: <wholes part>.<Fractional part> ");
  if (expression.matches("^[\\-].*") || expression.matches(".*[\\+\\*\\-\\/]{1}[\\s]{0,}[\\-].*"))
   throw new IllegalStateException("Expression invalid character: Unary minus is unacceptable ");

Answer (score 0):

Получится вот такая регулярка:

```
^(?=[^\.])\d*\.?((?=[^\.])\d*)$
```

Примеры входных строк:

```
123.123 //true
123.123 // false
.123 //false
123.123.123 //false
1 // true
123 // true
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но ваша регулярка не работает, можете проверить её здесь: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: В javascript не поддерживается эта функция. А вы каким языком пользуетесь?

Comment: @YuriyBochkarev я понял, вы пользуетесь java. Тогда нужно переделать выражение.

Comment: @YuriyBochkarev Я исправил в ответе на регулярку, которая работает в java. проверьте ее